# What is OpenCV's Discrete Fourier Transform real output formula?

Tags: opencv, dft

OpenCV's DFT function can give the DFT result as real and complex output values.

For the complex result the formula is the following: exp(-2*pi*i*j*k/N) where i=sqrt(-1) ([Reference](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#dft))

What is the formula for the real output?

I am  guessing it is this [formula](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/series/coefficients.php), but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s make some order.
DFT takes as input an N-tuple of complex values (that correspond to 2*N real values) and gives as output an N-tuple of complex values.
There is not a DFT for real and one for complex output values.
Probably you are referring to the situation where all the input values are real, i.e. each imaginary part is 0 (and it is not specified).
This is what is often needed in practical implementations of DFT.
In this case you always will get an N-tuple of complex values, but there is something interesting that reduces the intrinsic dimension of this result to the equivalent of N real values as for the input (note that I’ve written “the equivalent”, they are still complex).
I’ll show you an example.
N=7
INPUT
index, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
real part, 0, 2, 4, 1.5, 7, -3, 3
imaginary part, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

OUTPUT
index, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
real part, **14.5, -4.763307302, 3.286089778, -5.772782476**, -5.772782476, 3.286089778, -4.763307302
imaginary part, 0, **-3.656303338, -0.287959068, 11.26880763**, -11.26880763, 0.287959068, 3.656303338

Note that of the 14 output values only 7 are really necessary (bold), as the first imaginary part is always 0, and some values depends on the remaining values.

Now I‘ll show you how OPENCV treats this situation:

```
 double values[7] = {0, 2, 4, 1.5, 7, -3, 3};
 Mat x(Size(1,7), CV_64F, values);
 Mat X;
 dft(x, X); 
 cout << "X = "<< endl << X << endl;
```

It only outputs the strictly needed values.

P.S.: the second formula you link is a FT with infinite input values, not the Discrete version we are talking about.
Apart of this it is the same as the first one (remember the Euler’s formula: e^ix=cosx+isinx)

**UPDATED**
example of complex input, but with null imaginary part. That is the above example but with complex input.

```
 double values[14] = {0,0,  2,0,    4,0,    1.5,0,  7,0,    -3,0,   3,0};
 Mat x(Size(1,7), CV_64FC2, values);
 Mat X;
 dft(x, X, DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT); 
 cout << "X = "<< endl << X << endl ;
```

Comment: Hi Gino, thanks for your answer. Just to confirm if I understood you correctly...if my input values are only real numbers and I don't add the DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT flag to the cv::dft function it will give me the real numbers of the complex result as a result?

Comment: If your input values are only N real values and you don't add the DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT flag (it wouldn't work anyway with a real input) it will provide you N numbers among the 2*N it should output. Some of these numbers are from the real part, some from the imaginary part of the complete result (the bold ones).

Comment: Anyway, no. It will give you some numbers from the real part (4 in the example above), some from the imaginary part (3) of the complex result. 7 in total. With DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT if will give you 7 reals and 7 imaginaries=14.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that with N real input data and the DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT flag on, gives me back N real and N imaginaries result, which are my complex numbers. But I don't understand the result with out the DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT flag on. What do you mean it gives me "some" of the real and "some" of the imaginaries? It is still the same output as with DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT flag on just in a different representation or order?

Comment: Have you read what I've written above and tried out the code? Without the DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT flag it gives you back in a single row half of the numbers than before and some of those numbers are taken from the real part and some from the imaginary part. Please confront it with the first row of the table from the first link you provided. The documntation says: "In case of 1D transform of a real vector, the output looks like the first row of the matrix above."

Comment: As to the DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT flag on that gives back N reals and N imaginaries, try to modify the first lines of code I wrote above and insert that flag. It will provide 2*N numbers but the last ones are wrong. In my example it gives a series of -6.2774e+66 which are wrong.

Comment: Yes, I read it. Now it is clear as you mentioned "In case of 1D transform of a real vector, the output looks like the first row of the matrix above." this. This part wasn't clear to me in the documentation, but now as you wrote it and checked your example I understand the result. Thank you for your time and sorry if I was a bit novice in the topic.

Comment: Very nice explanation, I hope the text(especially) the input and the output value string could be formatted(aligned) . But there is no way to make the text bold when in `code` field.